# Implementing multiple attachments in one post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, attachment

What is the best way to handle multiple attachments in rails projects?

I have a post. I want to attach different kinds of content (audio/document/photo/video) and display them. 
I want to be able to use same attachments in different posts.
How I should implement this (if i use gem carrierwave, for example)?

This works, but i'd like to separate each kind of content to different models and tables (there will be lots of content):

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post_id, :image, :remote_image_url, :document, :remote_document_url, :video, :remote_video_url
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  mount_uploader :document, DocumentUploader
  mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader
end
```

*UPDATED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model Content (which you can associate to whatever model you like later) then do a has_many with nested Content model to add multiple Content items.  Dont forget to whitelist your extensions and MIME-types

Comment: And how do i separate Content into Video, Docs and Audio properly?

Comment: seperate? in show? edit? need more info for that.. you can condition by filetype.

Comment: why would you need different models? and if you do then create model for each type of content, to load content have different load buttons (like tumblr) then again use a one to many + nested form to attach to posts. You should note that the db doesn't care what type of content it is and I would keep all content (video, audio, image) in one model, and maybe set a contenttype based on MIMEtype, which you can always use again to set CSS for display.

Comment: Thank you! I want to separate into models to make it simple to browse AllVideos, for example and choose, which of them i want to use in my Post.